# Security permission issue when I ftp my dll in the web server

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working with web apps, all is well in my local drive but when I ftp it in the domain server. I got this error

> The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the
>   security policy. To grant this application the required permission
>   please contact your system administrator or change the application's
>   trust level in the configuration file.
>   System.Security.SecurityException:Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permission.FileIOPermission,mscorlib,Version=2.0.0.0,culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed

```
Version Information:Microsoft .Net Framework version 2.0.050727 4241 ASP.NET Version 2.0.50727 4223
```

Question? Does it affect my site? in VS my taget version is 3.5 and I guess in the server is 2.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: When do you get this error? are you attempting to run the file over the network by any chance? Is the dll marked "Untrusted" on the server so that you would have to right click it and have the option to "unblock" in the properties menu?

Comment: I got this error when I copied my dll in the server and run the site. Actually I ftp my DLL in the host server - I beleive the DLL is trusted

Comment: also I'm using go daddy for this

Answer (score 0):

If someone encountered this issues.. i got my issues because of this code

```
   string Path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
   System.IO.FileInfo Info = new System.IO.FileInfo(Path);
   string pageName = Info.Name;
```

since go daddy use medium security. they not allow file System.IO.FileInfo code. 
I changed my code and everything goes well